# linux linking to a .so , but still getting undefined reference

Tags: c++, linux, linker, undefined-reference

I am trying to create an executable that uses code from both static libraries and a shared library:

The static libs are several boost .a , `pthread` and `libbus.a`. The shared lib is a `libwrap.so`.

Note that the libwrap , uses code from `libbus` and `libbus` uses code from `pthread`. Finally, the executable uses code from `libwrap` and from `boost`.

Since the order of libraries included in the linker matters I am trying to find the "winning" sequence.

The linking stage is the following (pasted in multiple lines for convenience):

```
$ /usr/bin/c++   

    -Wall -Wextra 
    -fPIC 
    -fvisibility=hidden -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-long-long 
    -m64 
    -rdynamic 
    -D_UNICODE -DUNICODE 

    CMakeFiles/Wrapper_Test.dir/test.cpp.o

    /usr/local/lib/libboost_log.a 
     /usr/local/lib/libboost_system.a 
    /usr/local/lib/libboost_filesystem.a 
    /usr/local/lib/libboost_date_time.a 
    /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread.a 
    /usr/local/lib/libboost_log_setup.a 
    /usr/local/lib/libboost_chrono.a 
    -pthread  
    /home/nass/dev/Data_Parser/trunk/external/lib/linux64_gcc_release/libbus.a  

    -L/home/nass/dev/Data_Parser_build/lib                    #this is where the libwrap.so is located
    -Wl,-rpath,/home/nass/dev/Data_Parser_build/lib 
    -lwrap                                                    #the shared lib 

    -o ../../../bin/Wrapper_Test
```

The link error is

```
CMakeFiles/Wrapper_Test.dir/test.cpp.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to `wrapperNamespace::GetWrapper()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The `GetWrapper()` is located in `libwrap.so` of course, and I can verify it is a symbol that can be found in there:

```
$ nm -Ca ../../../lib/libwrap.so | grep GetWrapper  
00000000000423d6 t wrapperNamespace::GetWrapper()
```

However, the linker cannot find it. what am I doing wrong here?

### EDIT:

The linking command above is generated by the following CMakeLists.txt file:

```
set(TARGET_NAME Wrapper_Test)

#set(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR       ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
#set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
#set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})

# INCLUDE INTERNAL FOLDER
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/Wrapper) 

add_executable(${TARGET_NAME} test.cpp)

add_boost_lib(${TARGET_NAME} log system filesystem date_time thread log_setup chrono)
setup_libbus(${TARGET_NAME})    #the libbus.a
target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} -L../../../lib -lwrap)

set_property(TARGET ${TARGET_NAME} PROPERTY FOLDER test)
```

Comment: Read through the undefined-reference tag. It's likely that someone already asked and answered.

Comment: @IvanRubinson I have already gone through some of them. unfortunately I wasn't lucky so far. Still going through them though...

Comment: Could you show the cmake file you are using? There is probably some misconfiguration there

Comment: @paul-g you mean a misconfiguration that would not make it into the makefile? This link command is the result of a complex cmake (spanning across many folders). I was hoping to get the make command first, then propagate the necessary changes into cmake...

Comment: Well, linking libraries from cmake should just work via `target_link_libraries` and at most you will required some calls to `find_library`. It will figure out the order and everything and should also be portable (i.e. across different compilers, linkers etc.) To me it seems rather pointless to back propagate these changes, but I might be wrong.

Comment: @paul-g I feel more comfortable to solve this issue in `make` which I am more familiar with, rather than tread the cmake path - which is newer to me. (one step at a time kind of approach)

Comment: @nass I can understand that, but seriously, cmake is designed to abstract these details and make it easy to handle specifically these aspects, why work against it? All you need it to read on three function definitions and then use them :) Then you can look at what is generated.

Comment: @paul-g perhaps this cmake helps?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115834/discussion-between-paul-g-and-nass).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by looking at the `cmake` file which generates these lines.

It should be simple to add shared libaries to your path, for example:

```
find_library(
        LIBWrapper
        NAMES wrap
        PATHS /home/nass/dev/Data_Parser_build/lib
)
```

And then link them to your test file, for example

```
add_executable(test src/test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test ${LIBWrapper})
```

Similar should work for static libraries. This has the advantage that you don't have to deal with all the compiler/platform specific details which CMake supposedly handles for you, and which can be fairly complex & obscure.

*If your library is generated dynamically*, i.e. before cmake configuration time, you could just pass the appropriate linking flags to `target_link_libraries`:

```
target_link_libraries(test -L/home/nass/dev/Data_Parser_build/lib -lwrap)
```

I have used this suggestion in a few projects (e.g. https://github.com/caskorg/cask/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) which dynamically generate the library, then link against it. If this doesn't work I suspect something else is wrong.

Comment: hmmm, i am trying to do it through cmake. The problem I face is what `PATHS` to add, as the .so does not exist during cmake configuration time.

Comment: @nass I think you should have mentioned this in the question :D see my update, it's probably the easiest way to make this work

Comment: I have just incorporated it in the CMakeLists.txt but still I get the same linking error. I am appending the relevant cmake file in my question.. hopefully this can help out abit.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `-Wl,-Bstatic` in front of static libs and `-Wl,-Bdynamic` for the dynamic ones. You also need to use `-l` for libraries and `-L` for library paths.

Something like:

```
$ /usr/bin/c++ test.cpp.o  \
  -L/usr/local/lib \
  -Wl,-Bstatic \
  -lboost_log \
  -lsystem \
  -L/home/nass/dev/Data_Parser_build/lib \
  -Wl-Bdynamic \
  -Wl,-rpath,/home/nass/dev/Data_Parser_build/lib \
  -lwrap \
  -o ../../../bin/Wrapper_Test
```

looks better. Many things depend on the version of your compiler/linker/OS.

Comment: if It wasn't cmake generated, I , too, would use `-l` for the libs. I also tried with `-Wl,-Bstatic` , `-Wl,-Bdynamic` to no avail :(

Comment: Read the compiler/linker docs, I said it is the general idea about it. Details change from version to version.